# Python and regex to remove parenthesis in a file

Tags: python

xml file with about 2000 (texthere) parenthesis.  I need to remove the parenthesis and text within it.  I tried but am getting an error :(

```
import re, sys

    fileName = (sys.argv[2])


    with open(fileName) as f:

        input = f.read()
        output = re.sub(r'\(\w*\)', '', input)
        print fileName + " cleaned of all parenthesis"
```

and my error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eeamesX/work/data-scripts/removeParenFromXml.py", line 4, in <module>
    fileName = (sys.argv[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I changed the (sys.argv[1])...I get no errors but also the parenthesis in my file.xml do not get removed?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Have you tried `print sys.argv` to see what it holds?

Comment: What command line parameters did you pass? Python indexing is 0-based...

Comment: That has nothing to do with regex.

Comment: python removeparenthesis.py filename.xml is how I call it

Comment: I threw your `\(\w*\)` (and even @hjpotter92 's suggestion of `\(\w*?\)` into https://regex101.com/r/kB2lU1/3 and looking under `code generator` on the left, the regex is nearly the same as yours (with an additional `u` param next to the text string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're calling the script as follows:

```
python removeparenthesis.py filename.xml
```

the XML file name will appear under `sys.argv[1]`.

Also, you'd need to use lazy matching in your pattern:

```
r'\(\w*?\)'    # notice the ?
```

A better pattern would be:

```
r'\([^)]*\)'
```

Comment: I just tried this, and it seems to go into my file, but no parenthesis are removed.  File stays the same ?

Comment: @Eddwinn You're printing `filename`; and not the substituted string (`output`).

Answer (score 0):

Do you have nested parens?

```
stuff (words (inside (other) words) eww)
```

Will you have multiple groups of parens?

```
stuff (first group) stuff (second group)
```

Does text within parens have spaces?

```
stuff (single_word)
stuff (multiple words)
```

A simple regex could be `\(.*?\)` although you'll see that the nested parens are not caught (which is fine if you do NOT expect nested parens):

https://regex101.com/r/kB2lU1/1

**Edit:**

https://regex101.com/r/kB2lU1/2 may be able to handle some of those nested parens, but may still break depending on different types of edge cases.

You'll need to specify what kinds of edge cases you expect so the answer can be better tailored to your needs.

Comment: It is an easier one.. just (datafalse) or (variant)  No nested, or spaces

Comment: Your example with `\w*` suggests that you can have empty `()` parens, and you want to remove those as well. Is that correct?

Comment: I have no empty parenthesis..there are a thousand parenthesis containing those 2